# How can I structure this specific r-code to get a running shiny-app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Please mind that this is a question from a total Shinyapp beginner. Im trying to practice for my exam and just can't figure this out my self (I've researched a lot but it just doesn't make sense in my mind)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


#Creating the title and an Output with the id "exampleOne"
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Titanic"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "exampleOne")
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$exampleOne <- renderPlot({
#opening my dataset of the titanic, mutating the data for the next step
      titanic <- read.csv("titanic_data.csv",header = TRUE, sep=",")
      newdata <- mutate(titanic, Status = ifelse (Survived > 0,
                                                  'Survived',
                                                  'Dead'))
#Trying to create a graph, that shows how many people survived/died separated by sex
      ggplot( newdata, 
              aes(x = Sex, fill = Status)) 
              + geom_bar(position = "fill")
      labs(y= "Proportion")
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As I already said I'm a total beginner and totally lost! R and Shiny are kind of not my thing  I still hope someone can help me to get this going.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You should read about reactivity which will make it easier to work with input data and a lot of other things. Also, you need to add some sort of UI that the user can interact with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple: Though it took me some efforts to find:

You miss a `+` in the last but one ggplot() line:
Here is an example with the train.csv dataset

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


#Creating the title and an Output with the id "exampleOne"
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Titanic"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "exampleOne")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  

  
  
  output$exampleOne <- renderPlot({
    titanic <- read.csv("train.csv",header = TRUE, sep=",")
    newdata <- mutate(titanic, Status = ifelse (Survived > 0,
                                                'Survived',
                                                'Dead')) 
    ggplot( newdata, 
            aes(x = Sex, fill = Status)) +
     geom_bar(position = "fill")+ ### THIS + IS MISSING
    labs(y= "Proportion")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]